How can you dry out skin quickly and without a fridge?
Crispy poultry skin or pork belly skin is incredible but is best achieved by drying it out overnight in the fridge.
Are there any other methods that work to dry out skin preferably much quicker? Could you use a dehumidifier? Low oven at 40C? Blow fans at it on a wire rack? Anything else I haven't thought of?

blotting with paper towels does a decent job.  My understanding is that peking duck traditionally just used fans, but issues with hygiene were different back then

Fans sounds like a good idea. I'm happy to completely ignore overly-stringent advice from certain countries.

You could always put a filter in front of the fan if you were worried that it might be blowing bad stuff on the food (box fan with a filter for an air conditioner)

I've never needed to dry a chicken overnight, to get crispy skin I coat it with a drizzle of olive oil and sprinkle sea salt before roasting it in a convection oven. No drying necessary.
With pork I've found even drying it in the fridge doesn't help that much, unless you get it very quickly from the fridge to the oven. If it sits out for 5 minutes condensation will form and it's damp again. I let it sit out of the fridge for 30 minutes, then dry it using fragrance free paper towels, and then salting it before getting it into the oven.

I can get crispy skin without but I can get better skin if it's dryer and high pH so I'm asking for ways to dry to improve the skin.

You are going to need to keep the product below 4C (40F) so as not to create a hospitable environment for bacterial growth, so the most expedient way to do this is with a small fan inside a refrigerator.  At this point the only risk would be blowing meat juices onto uncovered food, potentially cross-contaminating what is already in the fridge.  If you are mindful and careful, this can speed things up a bit.  However, what you are trying to achieve, goes beyond removing surface moisture, so this is still going to take some time.
If you are only talking about the skin alone.  You could use a dehydrator, but now you should ensure the temperature gets above 60C (140F).  Even better, if you simply want crispy chicken skin, place it flat on a parchment covered sheet pan.  Place another piece of parchment on top, followed by the bottom of another sheet pan.  Roast in the oven until crispy.

I have an outdoor shed which is 4c at this time of year so a fan will be fine. I'm also not too bothered about keeping a large turkey or belly on ribs for example at 10C for a few hours. This would be for skin still attached though.

Putting it in an outdoor shed isn't going to help, you're just going to blow cold, damp air over it. A refrigerator is a dry environment, which is why one of the methods is to keep it in, uncovered.

Surely that depends on the outdoor humidity?

As the temperature drops relative humidity increases, so at night it's going to be wetter than the day. You'd have live at high altitude or in a very dry climate for a shed to work. You'll need to think about how to keep vermin from getting to it.

I get quite crispy skin on chicken merely by roasting in a convection (fan) oven (with the skin still on the meat.) I can't speak to pork belly skin.
You can pack it in salt (or sugar), which will draw out water. That will also affect the flavor, of course. Whether that effect is a plus or a minus for you will depend on you. I don't do that, but it is a normal way to somewhat quickly remove moisture.

I can get crispy skin without but I can get better skin if it's dryer and high pH so I'm asking for ways to dry to improve the skin.
